# How to detect the desktop environment in a bash script?

Tags: bash, desktop-environment, bash-script

I am writing a `bash` script that needs to know which desktop environment (XFCE, Unity, KDE, LXDE, Mate, Cinnamon, GNOME2, GNOME3,... ) is running.

How can I obtain that information?

Comment: that is hard because even if you are in a GNOME session and just started one KDE program like kwrite all the KDE infrastructure like KDE daemon and kdeinit will be running.

Comment: You pretty much can't, not reliably. Why do you need to know? This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Gilles Good question. I am writing a speciality script for `xplanet` and would like to [automatically refresh the desktop background](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116541/39845) with commands specific to the desktop environment. If you like to [post an answer to that problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116541/39845), please, follow the link.

Comment: What if there is none?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main problem with checking the `DESKTOP_SESSION` is that it is set by the display manager rather than the desktop session and is subject to inconsistencies. For `lightdm` on Debian, the values come from the names of files under `/usr/share/xsessions/`. `DESKTOP_SESSION` reflects the desktop environment if a specific selection is made at log in, however the `lightdm-xsession` is always used the default session.

`GDMSESSION` is another option, but seems to have a similar predicament (it is the same value as `DESKTOP_SESSION` for me).

`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` looks like a good choice, however it is currently not in the [XDG standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and thus not always implemented. See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/xdg@lists.freedesktop.org/msg06587.html) for a discussion of this. This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/227669) shows its values for different distros/desktops, I can also confirm it is currently not available for me on XFCE.

The reasonable fallback for `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` not existing would be to try `XDG_DATA_DIRS`. Provided the data files for the desktop environment are installed in a directory bearing its name, this approach should work. This will hopefully be the case for all distros/desktops!

The following (with GNU grep) tests for XFCE, KDE and Gnome:

```
echo "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" | grep -Eo 'xfce|kde|gnome'
```

POSIX compatible:

```
echo "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" | sed 's/.*\(xfce\|kde\|gnome\).*/\1/'
```

To combine with checking `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`:

```
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = "" ]
then
  desktop=$(echo "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" | sed 's/.*\(xfce\|kde\|gnome\).*/\1/')
else
  desktop=$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
fi

desktop=${desktop,,}  # convert to lower case
echo "$desktop"
```

Comment: I like this. According to [this overview](http://askubuntu.com/a/227669/164341), there will only be a problem with Cinnamon. However, this might eventually be resolved by opening a bug report with Linux Mint.

Comment: @on4aa MATE is not on the list, it is likely to have the same issue. `apt-file` is also a good tool to see where the various desktops install to.

Comment: This solution is still leaning heavily towards Debian based distros. None of the methods discussed work on any of the Red Hat based distros I have access to (Fedora, CentOS, etc.).

Comment: @slm interesting, does `XDG_DATA_DIRS` not exist or does it just not contain anything useful?

Comment: @Graeme - Doesn't exist. This was kind of my finding w/ my A too. There seems to be a divide b/w the Debian vs. RH distros at this level. I think Gilles comment is actually spot on though, this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @slm very true, I think the OP is probably better trying to do what he wants to do for each desktop in a `||` style. Still this question has been asked on other SE sites, I think we have the best set of answers.

Comment: @slm, what about my process tree walking stuff, how would that fare?

Comment: @Graeme - do you mean your script? That returns a blank line.

Comment: @slm, my other answer. If it the script returns a blank line then its broken :(. It will only work for xfce, but it is the process of searching descendants of the parent of `Xorg` I'm asking about.

Comment: On Arch Linux with Xfce, `echo "$XDG_DATA_DIRS"` returns `/usr/local/share:/usr/share`, and so is not useful.

Comment: `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` works for me on `GNOME Shell 3.26.2` - `Debian "buster"` and on `xfce 4.10.1` - `Debian "jessie"`. `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` is empty on both!

Comment: `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` was specified in [version 1.2](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ape.html) of the [freedesktop standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).

Answer (score 10):

#### Method #1 - $DESKTOP_SESSION

I think you can find out by interrogating the environment variable `$DESKTOP_SESSION`. I'm not entirely positive how widely supported this is but in my limited testing it appears to be available on Fedora & Ubuntu.

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
gnome
```

Another choice is the `$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP` variable.

#### Method #2 - wmctrl

There is also this method that makes use of `wmctrl`.

```
$ wmctrl  -m
Name: GNOME Shell
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

#### References

- [How to determine which window manager is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running)

Comment: I am truncating at the first letter because plain `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` yields `xubuntu` on my machine.

Comment: Mine gives `lightdm-xsession`

Comment: This approach came from this AU Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running

Comment: Especially [this answer is very informative.](http://askubuntu.com/a/227669/164341) Could it be that `$GDMSESSION` consistently yields the same results as `$DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: @Graeme Which variable on what desktop?

Comment: @on4aa - `$GDMSESSION` makes me nervous since it's likely only geared towards DE that are either using GDM or GNOME based DE. GDM = GNOME Display Manager.

Comment: @on4aa `DESKTOP_SESSION` on xfce.

Comment: on xfce, my DESKTOP_SESSION is `default` (mint 15)

Comment: Debian showed `default` for this too. A default install of GNOME 3.

Comment: `wmctrl -m` on Ubuntu (Unity): `Name: Metacity`

Comment: `$DESKTOP_SESSION` shows `default` for KDE under Fedora 20.

Comment: `$DESKTOP_SESSION` worked on Arch Linux Xfce.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this [bash script](https://github.com/alexeevdv/dename). It can detect desktop environment name and version.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function detect_gnome()
{
    ps -e | grep -E '^.* gnome-session$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    return 0
    fi
    VERSION=`gnome-session --version | awk '{print $2}'`
    DESKTOP="GNOME"
    return 1
}

function detect_kde()
{
    ps -e | grep -E '^.* kded4$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        return 0
    else    
        VERSION=`kded4 --version | grep -m 1 'KDE' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
        DESKTOP="KDE"
        return 1
    fi
}

function detect_unity()
{
    ps -e | grep -E 'unity-panel' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    return 0
    fi
    VERSION=`unity --version | awk '{print $2}'`
    DESKTOP="UNITY"
    return 1
}

function detect_xfce()
{
    ps -e | grep -E '^.* xfce4-session$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    return 0
    fi
    VERSION=`xfce4-session --version | grep xfce4-session | awk '{print $2}'`
    DESKTOP="XFCE"
    return 1
}

function detect_cinnamon()
{
    ps -e | grep -E '^.* cinnamon$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    return 0
    fi
    VERSION=`cinnamon --version | awk '{print $2}'`
    DESKTOP="CINNAMON"
    return 1
}

function detect_mate()
{
    ps -e | grep -E '^.* mate-panel$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    return 0
    fi
    VERSION=`mate-about --version | awk '{print $4}'`
    DESKTOP="MATE"
    return 1
}

function detect_lxde()
{
    ps -e | grep -E '^.* lxsession$' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    return 0
    fi

    # We can detect LXDE version only thru package manager
    which apt-cache > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    which yum > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
        VERSION='UNKNOWN'
    else
        # For Fedora
        VERSION=`yum list lxde-common | grep lxde-common | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F '-' '{print $1}'`
    fi
    else    
    # For Lubuntu and Knoppix
    VERSION=`apt-cache show lxde-common /| grep 'Version:' | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F '-' '{print $1}'`
    fi
    DESKTOP="LXDE"
    return 1
}

function detect_sugar()
{
    if [ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" == "sugar" ];
    then
    VERSION=`python -c "from jarabe import config; print config.version"`
    DESKTOP="SUGAR"
    else
    return 0
    fi
}


DESKTOP="UNKNOWN"
if detect_unity;
then
    if detect_kde;
    then
    if detect_gnome;
    then
        if detect_xfce;
        then
        if detect_cinnamon;
        then
            if detect_mate;
            then
            if detect_lxde;
            then
                detect_sugar
            fi
            fi
        fi
        fi
    fi
    fi
fi


if [ "$1" == '-v' ];
then
    echo $VERSION
else
    if [ "$1" == '-n' ];
    then
    echo $DESKTOP
    else
    echo $DESKTOP $VERSION
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Works on Arch Linux

Comment: I stole your idea to check just for Xfce in my script: `ps -e | grep -E '^.* xfce4-session$' > /dev/null` `(($? == 0)) && ...`

Comment: this did not work for me on `GNOME Shell 3.26.2` I got `UNKNOWN`. No output from `gnome-session --version` working for me is `gnome-shell --version | awk '{print $3}'` I also did not get anything out of `ps -e | grep -E '^.* gnome-session$'`. This seems to be because of `-b` at the end of `gnome-session-b`. Removing the `$` works or just simply `ps -e | grep 'gnome-session'`. With this changes the script is working. I get `GNOME 3.26.2`

Answer (score 3):

Standards evolved a lot since question was made in 2014.

For **2021**, my recommendation is: use only the official `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.

Be careful that officially it is a *colon-separated **list*** (like `$PATH`), so don't assume it only contains a single value, even if it is in most DEs. For example, Ubuntu's Unity set it to `Unity:Unity7:ubuntu`.

If you prefer to handle a single value, use `$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`.

Official standards:

- [XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys), defined in the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) since its [version 1.2](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#idm45632483466576)
- [XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html#desktop=), best described in [`systemd`'s PAM](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html)

Other related environment variables should be considered legacy by now.

A bash function to properly check a given string against the current desktop environment:

```bsh
# Encapsulates the mess that DE detection was, is, or will ever be...
# Without arguments, check if in a Desktop Environment at all
# Subshell is intentional so we don't have to save/restore IFS
# Case-insensitive comparison
is_desktop_environment() (
    local de=${1:-}
    local DEs=${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP:-}

    # Shortcut: If de is empty, check if empty DEs
    if [[ -z "$de" ]]; then if [[ "$DEs" ]]; then return; else return 1; fi; fi

    # Lowercase both
    de=${de,,}; DEs=${DEs,,}

    # Check de against each DEs component
    IFS=:; for DE in $DEs; do if [[ "$de" == "$DE" ]]; then return; fi; done

    # Not found
    return 1
)
```

Testing:

```bsh
for de in "" Ubuntu Gnome KDE Unity; do
    if is_desktop_environment "$de"; then
        echo "Yes, this is ${de:-a DE}"
    else
        echo "No,  this is not ${de:-a DE}"
    fi
done

Yes, this is a DE
Yes, this is Ubuntu
No,  this is not Gnome
No,  this is not KDE
Yes, this is Unity
```

Answer (score 1):

That probably depends on the situation. If you know which display manager is used then it may be that this one puts this information in a environment variable.

If that is not the case then I guess you have to check for every DE you want to be able to identify. All of them should introduce their own environment variables.

Comment: I am wondering whether `echo ${DESKTOP_SESSION:0:1}` would do the trick? As far as I could test, it returns `u` for Unity and `x` for XFCE. Hopefully some folk will chime in for KDE and other desktops.

Comment: @on4aa It's `echo ${DESKTOP_SESSION} kde-plasma-safe` for my KDE. Whyever "safe"...

Comment: Are there some Linux Mint Mate/Cinnamon users here? E17, LXDE, etc. are also welcome...

Answer (score 1):

You could look for running `Xorg` processes. The parent of this should be your display manager. Its descendants should give an indication of what desktop environment is running. On my system, the display manager executes  itself (with different parameters). This then spawns `x-session-manager` which is symlinked to `xfce4-session`. This may be enough, but all the children of this are related to my desktop environment. Finding them via the process tree should be the best way to exclude elements of other window systems started by various programs (or perhaps deliberately).

My first thought was that it would be be best to look for the window manager associated with your desktop environment, but often a different one can be configured to run (eg `xmonad` in Gnome) so this is not robust. The best one to look for is probably the one which manages the actual desktop, eg `xfdesktop` or whatever element of the desktop environment you actally need for your script to work :)

#### Example

Here is an example using [procps-ng](https://gitorious.org/procps) (`-C` and `--ppid` are not POSIX). It assumes the is only one instance of `Xorg`.

**This is just an example that works for the xfce desktop. A full working example requires an investigation in to the processes that each desktop system uses, just as most of the other solutions require investigation into how environmental variables are set in various other desktop systems.**

```
X=Xorg

search_descendants ()
{
  ps h -o comm --ppid $1 |
    grep -E '^(xfdesktop|another_desktop_process)$' &&
    return 0

  for pid in $(ps h -o pid --ppid $1)
  do
    search_descendants $pid && return 0
  done

  return 1
}

dm_pid=$(ps h -o ppid -C "$X")

case "$(search_descendants $dm_pid)" in
  xfdesktop)
    desktop=xfce
    ;;
  another_desktop_process)
    desktop=another_desktop
    ;;
  *)
    desktop=unknown
    ;;
esac

echo $desktop
```

Comment: This returns `unknown` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @on4aa, that was not meant to be a complete solution. This was supposed to be an example that works for the xfce desktop. A full working example requires an investigation in to the processes that each desktop system uses. I thought that would have been obvious from *reading* the code.

Comment: @Greame You are right; I was a bit too quick and overlooked the unfinished `another_desktop` outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If the environmental variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` is available, it should tell you.

```
# echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
KDE
```

Comment: Not a surprise but just so other's are aware that pass by this Q&A: doesn't exist in in GNOME DE.

Comment: Indeed, with emphasis on "if available". See also this [Askubuntu answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/227669/164341).

Answer (score 1):

From all the experimenting reported in the numerous comments, I think its my duty as the OP to come up with a consensus answer. (Rest assured, I would be happy to review this answer should contrasting data become available.)

For now, it seems best to take our lead from `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` when this variable is defined. If not, `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` may provide the desired information, more so than the first letter of `${DESKTOP_SESSION:0:1}`.

Comment: I have no `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`. I think the main problem with these is variables in that they are set by the display manager rather than the desktop environment and so there is some inconsistency. When I choose a default session (xfce) with lightdm `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` gives `lightdm-xsession` which is an amalgamation of `lightdm` and `x-session-manager`, the process used to start my desktop (symlinked to `xfce4-session`). I imagine installing with a different default session will just use a different symlink and yield the same `DESKTOP_SESSION`

Comment: Notably, if I specifically choose XFCE or Gnome from the display manager, `DESKTOP_SESSION` will actually say `xfce` or `gnome`

Comment: This solution is still leaning heavily towards Debian based distros. None of the methods discussed work on any of the Red Hat based distros I have access to (Fedora, CentOS, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This works on both Ubuntu 18.10 (cosmic) [lxqt type] and Mint 19 (tara) [cinnamon type]:

```
$  set | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Capture the result into a variable, and execute further necessary code via capable analytic logic (case stmt, if/then) which includes any/all recognized types from there; and/or function gracefully when unrecognized types are in use.

Comment: Works also with Xubuntu LTS 18.04.